# Is it possible to have access to all the strings written before, on a page, with PHP?

Tags: php

Does PHP give access to all the strings that have been outputted to a page?

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com">Link</a>
<?php
echo 'hello world';
echo 'something else';

$s = get_all_output();    // does this exist ?
```

Of course I could replace every instance of `echo 'some text';` by an initial `$s = '';` and then `$s .= 'some text';`.

But without this trick, how to get the current page as a string?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the output buffering of PHP (cf. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php).

```
<?php
ob_start(); // turn on buffering
echo "Hello ";
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); // end buffering and clear buffer without "displaying it".

// process $out which contains "Hello "
echo "$out";
```

Comment: Does it work as well if I have HTML outside php tags?  Example: `<?php
ob_start(); echo "Hello "; ?> <div>Hello World</div> <?php ob_get_contents(); ?>`

Comment: I tried the last thing, and yes it works too. Great!

Answer (score 0):

You must insert:

```
    ob_start();
```

at the beginig of your php code and then

```
    $s = ob_get_contents();
```

at the point where you want to get the content of the page.